# Group and sum DateTime object by date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the best way to group objects by date and add them all up to create a single JavaScript object? I prefer code readability and lesser lines of code over performance as the application is not data intensive. Moreover there are going to be lots people who are going to make changes after I'm done with my internship.

Here is some sample data

```
[
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},

    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4}

]
```

I want to create this out of the above data.

```
[ {"Date":"2015-01-01", "cp":4, "pc":12}, {"Date":"2015-01-02", "cp":4, "pc"12} ]
```

If you notice, the resultant JavaScript object is the sum total of all the columns on that particular date and replace timestamp by date.

We already use [moment.js](http://www.momentjs.org) in the application, so I have it at disposal. If you think moment can solve the problem in a neater fashion, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Iterate your array of objects *(`$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection.)*
- Convert `UTC` format date string to `ISO` format using `toISOString()` method.
- Maintain common array for date so that you can easily map your repeated date location using `indexOf()` method.

**Here is the Code:**

```
var arr = [
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},

  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
  {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4}
];
var resultArr = [];
var dateArr = [];   

$.each(arr, function () {
// Easiest way to get your required date format
   var date = new Date(this.Timestamp).toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').split(' ')[0];
   var index = dateArr.indexOf(date);
   if (index == -1) {
       dateArr.push(date);
       var obj = {Date: date, cp: this.cp, pc: this.pc};
       resultArr.push(obj);
   } 
   else {
       resultArr[index].cp += this.cp;
       resultArr[index].pc += this.pc;
   }
});
console.log(resultArr); // [ {"Date":"2015-01-01", "cp":4, "pc":12}, {"Date":"2015-01-02", "cp":4, "pc"12} ]
```

Hope this may helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks :). I get this Uncaught TypeError: $.each is not a function(…)(anonymous function)

Comment: I think you have conflict with `$`. you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Works now. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine means, please accept your answer. So that others can findout answer quickly

Comment: Will wait for a day. I feel that it can be further reduced. I am being careful because this piece of code will be used across various categories. Will definitely accept it if I can't find a better answer.

Comment: To make the code a little better save `dateArr.indexOf(date)` into a variable before the if statement (better performance). Since you are using moment you can get date value with this code: `var date = moment(this.Timestamp, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD');` (better readability)

Comment: @VincenzoC Makes sense.

Comment: @VincenzoC I agreed your answer and will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe a simple utility library such as [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) could do the job, however, this looks like a task plain old vanilla Javascript can take on by itself.

Check out the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, or probably better yet an [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that takes in a sorting function applying logic to a given object's `.Timestamp` property.

Edit: something like

```
yourArray.sort(function(objA, objB){
  return objA.Timestamp > objB.TimeStamp ? -1 : 1;
});
```

may work.

EDIT: I see now you are trying to merge dates. In that case, I would say `Array.prototype.map` chained with `Array.prototype.reduce` is a possible path to go down. You could also (messily) use `Array.prototype.filter` to push all arrays of a given date into a single array, and so on for each date.

Edit:

How about a reduce, then?

```
var thingYouWant = yourArray.reduce(function(summed, current){
    date = changeIntoOnlyDayDate(current.Timestamp);
    var found = false;
    summed.forEach(function(obj){
        if(obj.Timestamp === date){ obj.cp++; found = true;};
    }
    if(!found){summed.push(turnThisDateIntoDesiredObject(date))}

    }
    return summed;
    }, []);
```

Comment: The code that you've given will not solve my problem. I want to group and add them all. I don't want to sort. Say entries 1, 2, 3 and 4 were made on 1st January, I want to add them up to get the total as on 1st January.

Comment: I never thought of reduce and filter. Upvoted for that. I ended up using Jeni's answer so am not accepting your solution. :)

Comment: With all due respect, it looks like you're not functioning within the spirit of the site. Your responses give off the impression that you're looking for someone to do a piece of code logic for you, when really questions should be more general - "in what ways can I do x or why," not, "Here's an object, please sort it for me within these criteria." What do you think programmers get paid for?

Comment: Advice taken. Will be careful next time. I did my research though, implemented the sort in the server side via Python (new to JavaScript) first instead of doing it on the client side. Researched a few libraries in JavaScript and thought or parsing using regular expressions. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var timeArray=[
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 01 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},

    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 00:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 01:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 02:57:00 GMT","cp":2,"pc":2},
    {"Timestamp":"Thu, 02 Jan 2015 03:57:00 GMT","cp":0,"pc":4}
]

var object = {}, resultArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
    var date = timeArray[i].Timestamp;
    var localDateString = new Date(date).getFullYear() + '-' + (new Date(date).getMonth() + 1) + '-' + new Date(date).getDate();
    if (object[localDateString]) {
        object[localDateString].cp += timeArray[i].cp;
        object[localDateString].pc += timeArray[i].pc;
    } else {
        timeArray[i].Date = localDateString;
        delete timeArray[i].Timestamp;
        object[localDateString] = timeArray[i];
    }
}

for (var prop in object)
    resultArray.push(object[prop]);

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: This works. May have to change a bit to meet my needs. Thanks a lot. I will accept the solution in case I don't get a better solution :)