# Create object from grouped up datetimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an array of datetimes - i need an object where the dates are grouped up for the keys, value should be an array of the times for that date. Source:

```
[
    "2019-02-18T11:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-18T13:00:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-19T13:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-19T16:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T17:00:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T17:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T18:00:00+01:00"
]
```

I need this:

```
{
    '2019-02-18': [
        '11:30:00+01:00',
        '13:00:00+01:00'
    ],
    '2019-02-19': [
        '13:30:00+01:00',
        '16:30:00+01:00'
    ],
    ...
}
```

One solution will be to loop the array, strip the first 10 chars and match other datetimes - not really nice tbh.

Comment: Did you even try your *"one solution"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group and sum DateTime object by date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031750/group-and-sum-datetime-object-by-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let data = ["2019-02-18T11:30:00+01:00","2019-02-18T13:00:00+01:00","2019-02-19T13:30:00+01:00","2019-02-19T16:30:00+01:00","2019-02-20T17:00:00+01:00","2019-02-20T17:30:00+01:00","2019-02-20T18:00:00+01:00"]

let op = data.reduce(( op, inp ) => {
  let [key,value] = inp.split('T')
  if( op[key] ){
    op[key].push(value)
  } else {
    op[key] = [value]
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in conjunction with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const input = [
    "2019-02-18T11:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-18T13:00:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-19T13:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-19T16:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T17:00:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T17:30:00+01:00",
    "2019-02-20T18:00:00+01:00"
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, date) =>
{
    let [m, d, t] = date.match(/(.+)T(.+)/);
    acc[d] = [...(acc[d] || []), t];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```